# Installing checkinstall locally

Tags: software-installation, make, home, checkinstall

I'm trying to install [checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/index.php) locally in my home directory. Though, in the `INSTALL` file is only described how to do a system wide installation:

```
Simple enough:

make
su
make install
checkinstall
```

Instead I'd like to use the `configure` script this way:

```
./configure --prefix=~/opt/
make
make install
checkinstall
```

but checkinstall distribution doesn't provide `configure`.

I think it's possible to do what I want meddling with make files.

Answer (score 1):

The first few lines of the Makefile:

```
# Where to install.
PREFIX=/usr/local
BINDIR=$(PREFIX)/sbin
LCDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib/checkinstall/locale
CONFDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib/checkinstall
```

You just need to change the PREFIX:

```
PREFIX=/home/youruser/opt
```

Comment: A similar change should be made for `installwatch/Makefile`.